# How to sort taxonomy terms by their tid?

Tags: 7, theming, taxonomy-terms

I'm using a custom module to print taxonomy terms as **filters** inside a View.

[image]

I want to sort the taxonomy terms by their tids not by their names.

The below is from the `custom-filter.tpl.php`:

```
<?php foreach($data as $tid => $name): ?>
<div data-filter=".filter-<?php print $tid; ?>" class="cbp-filter-item">
  <?php print $name; ?>
  <?php print $text_counter; ?>
</div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

**How can I sort the taxonomy terms by their tids?**

Comment: Drupal doesn't have anything in particular, unless yo're makig the query yourself and can make the changes that way. Just use php sort functions otherwise

Comment: Thanks @Clive. So, I have to find the PHP way. Any help on this?

Comment: An alternative non-coding approach would be to use Views instead, you can sort it by tid there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Base on your code, I think the key for the `$data` is tid.

You can just add `<?php ksort($data);?>` before your foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I had already tried ksort but my structure had been wrong. Yours work correctly. ;)